# dig for windows works in cmd, but it doesn't work in system()

Tags: c++, c, dig

dig for windows works in cmd, but it doesn't work in system()

**This is in cmd:**
[image]

**This is my code:**

```
system("  \"C:\\Windows\\System32\\dig.exe google.com\"  ");
```

and the **result**:
[image]

Comment: Either double all the back-slashes, or else change them to forward-slashes.

Comment: Did you intend to type `system(" "C:\Windows\System32\dig.exe google.com" ");` instead of `system("C:\Windows\System32\dig.exe google.com");`?

Comment: Is `C:\Windows\System32\dig.exe` the correct path to the executable?

Comment: I want to use "dig google.com" in system() @h0r53

Comment: yes, it's the correct path. @Kevin

Comment: If it worked from a command line without a path, it should work from `system()` call without a path too. Have you tried `system("dig google.com");`?

Comment: yes, it's still doesn't work. @WeatherVane

Comment: Are you sure it *is* `dig.exe` with that suffix?